# Maven Shade Plugin transformer to merge text files, discarding duplicate lines

Tags: maven, apache-httpclient-4.x, maven-shade-plugin, apache-httpclient-5.x

Is there a [resource transformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html) available for the [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) that will merge text files of the same name as does the [AppendingTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer), but throw out duplicate lines (i.e. perform a union of the lines in all files with the indicated name)?

Specifically I have multiple libraries that use different versions of Apache HTTP client and therefore I end up with multiple `mozilla/public-suffix-list.txt`. I want to get rid of the warning. I know I can single one out one of the dependencies for removal of its `mozilla/public-suffix-list.txt` file, but I'm putting this configuration in a parent POM to be used in projects that may not use one or other of the libraries, so I'd prefer a general solution of merging.

As a side note, does anyone know if the Apache HTTP client libraries will break in some way if I simply merge the various `mozilla/public-suffix-list.txt` files into one large file, i.e. essentially duplicating most of the entries? (I wonder if the Apache HTTP client merely reads the files into a set, discarding duplicates, in which case it would be fine just to blindly merge them.)